# Oracle APEX checkbox order of the items

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I created a checkbox that has a list of days of the week Monday-Friday. I set it to a static list of values:

```
STATIC:Monday;Monday,Tuesday;Tuesday, Wednesday;Wednesday,Thursday;Thursday,Friday;Friday
```

When displayed on the page, the order of the items is as follows:

```
Wednesday
Friday
Monday
Thursday
Tuesday
```

How can i ensure the items are displayed in the correct order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `STATIC`, use `STATIC2` (note the trailing number **2**).

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E39147_04/app_contrls002.htm) says:

> STATIC results in the values being sorted alphabetically by display value. STATIC2 results in the values being displayed in the order they are entered in the list.